# Getting POST url from a pages form, what am i missing?

Tags: php

I'm trying to do a post to a page so don't have to complete the form but cannot seem to get it working.

Form is here:

http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/proof-of-delivery

what I'm trying to do:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/proof-of-delivery?ctl00_maincontent_ctl02_btnDoPODLookup=true&amp;ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbAccountRef=01484267&amp;ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbConsignmentRef=2837&amp;ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbDestPostcode=AL15BY");
```

> ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbAccountRef=01484267
>   ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbConsignmentRef=2837
>   ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbDestPostcode=AL15BY

Those are the 3 I'm passing but maybe I'm missing other stuff from the URL which is why its not working, I'm not sure if someone can see from the form itself what I might be missing.

** UPDATED WITH CURL **

```
<base href="http://www.tuffnells.co.uk"/>

<?php

if (isset($_GET['orderid'])){
    $url = 'http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/PODLookupResults.aspx?__EVENTTARGET=&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATEGUID=7ca82b1d-b722-4cdc-b74a-b338d8577ffa&__VIEWSTATE=&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEdAAevVXD1oYELeveMr0vHCmYPaomE%2FDwQD43eOdzEj3p%2Fm4U4pgxq6tlupSJfQZQBazFFj%2F1LmlGLyHFagz1yHZm8bjowVgAJ8C3e%2B2bVMPt91KjXCHjnAsonQDi2zFSuasUVzpitHiLDCDtiLHCjNCQG4CxrbV5VPFqBeOgs2X52AD%2FEb%2BYR%2BEJ68PaN2CiyKzE%3D&ctl00%24ctl16%24tbHeaderSearch=Search..&ctl00%24maincontent%24tbAccountRef=01484267&ctl00%24maincontent%24btnDoPODLookup=Search+Again';
    $fields = array(
        'ctl00%24maincontent%24tbConsignmentRef' => urlencode($_POST['orderid']),
        'ctl00%24maincontent%24tbDestPostcode' => urlencode($_GET['postcode'])
    );

    //url-ify the data for the POST
    foreach($fields as $key=>$value) { $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; }
    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    //open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    //set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, count($fields));
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);

    //execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //close connection
    curl_close($ch);
}

?>
```

http://ambientlounge.com/external/ukTracking.php?orderid=2837&postcode=AL15BY

Comment: `file_get_contents()` doesn't *post* anything. You need to look at something like cURL.

Comment: Ok, new to php so not sure how however if you go to here: http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/proof-of-delivery?ctl00_maincontent_ctl02_btnDoPODLookup=true&amp;ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbAccountRef=01484267&amp;ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbConsignmentRef=2837&amp;ctl00$maincontent$ctl02$tbDestPostcode=AL15BY it does not work... so guess need to work out the right url to post to?

Comment: The URL does not accept query strings, so adding a query string will *never* work. You have to learn something like [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Comment: Im looking into curl at the moment - ill edit with curl example, can you let me know if ok as at the moment dont think it is.

Comment: side note: It _can_ be done via `file_get_contents` by setting the `content`property of an [http option context](http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php) passed to `file_get_contents`.  ....but can be done via curl as well (and the session/cookie handling will probably come inhandy since there seems to be a login involved).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to make a post like this.
for example:

```
$curl = curl_init();
        $options =  array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_URL => 'http://www.tuffnells.co.uk/proof-of-d...');//etc
        curl_setopt_array($curl,$options);
        echo $options[CURLOPT_URL]; //will print you all the path- just for testing.
        curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
```

hope it helps...

Comment: Ive tried this: http://ambientlounge.com/external/ukTracking.php?orderid=2837&postcode=AL15BY - its passing to the URL but how can i return the content of the site as i need to then push to ajax / jquery and use just the div i need from the page. is that possible?

Comment: what do you mean with : "return the content of the site as i need to then push to ajax / jquery" you are sending it... do you wants to use this content after sending it?

Comment: I have a html page on aother site which i will pass orderid and postcode from to a ajax call to that php curl file so grab the page contents from tuffuneel website which is tracking information then want to return it so i can display on the external page if that makes sense.

Comment: I hope it will helps... you can use this : isset($_GET['/the name of the button/']) 
to get the info that return from the server. hope i understood it right.